# Using GNU Assembler to dynamically create a struct and returning a pointer to it

Tags: struct, gnu-assembler

Using the GNU Assembler I'm trying to call malloc to create a C struct, insert values into that struct and return a pointer to that struct.  Below is the struct:

```
struct node {
    void     *next;     
    void     *last; 
    char     *name;     
    int      id;        
    uint8_t  number;
    uint8_t  numberTwo;
    uint8_t  numberThree;
    uint8_t  numberFour;
}
```

Below is the GNU Assembly that I'm using:

```
    push %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    subl $0x1c, %esp
    #movl $20, (%esp)   #I've tried this but it doesn't seem to help
    push $20            #Struct is 20 bytes
    call malloc     
    test %eax, %eax
    jz allocateFailed
    jmp allocateOK

allocateFailed:
    leave
    ret

allocateOK:
    movl 8(%ebp), %edx
    movl %edx, 8(%eax)
    movl 12(%ebp), %edx
    movl %edx, 12(%eax)
    leave
    ret
```

I've updated the code to stay away from using the %ebx register and taking a look at an Objdump of the function that is how the assembler handled this.

I'm getting the parameters fine but when I try to put them in the newly created struct I get a seg fault.  Below is the core dump.

Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted.
0  0xb7727424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()

Below is what I get what I run a backtrace in gdb:

```
0  allocateOK () at new_student.s:25
1  0x00000014 in ?? ()      #Not sure what this is coming from
2  0xb7fc5a20 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
3  0x080485ed in test ()    #function that calls and passes in the parameters
4  0x080487b4 in main ()
```

I've also written this function in C and compiled with the --gstabs and -o and used objdump to get a look at it.  I seems to be pretty close to mine but I just can't seem to figure it out.

```
sub    $0x1c,%esp
movl   $0x14,(%esp)
call   8048350 <malloc@plt>
mov    0x20(%esp),%edx
mov    %edx,0xc(%eax)
mov    0x24(%esp),%edx
mov    %edx,0x8(%eax)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  I've never used assembly (only C) to create and work with structs.  I've done some research and have been trying a few things but I just seem to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Best guess: since you're using `%ebx` without saving and restoring it, you're corrupting something that the caller had in it, causing problems after your routine returns.  Also, you're only setting the `name` and `id` fields of your newly allocated struct; the rest will contain uninitialized garbage.  Use a debugger to get a stack trace of where the abort occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I've updated the code and the question.